# Hide ::before on active item just while hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this structure:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="menuitem active">see all projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="menuitem">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="menuitem">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When `.active` can be one of the three (it just hightlight the page the user is in).
The problem is that I'm creating an "arrow" hightlight on `.active` item via `::before` selector and I want that if the user hovers over any item, the `::before` dissapears JUST WHILE hover.

This is how it looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZxPW.png

And on hover looks like this (see the problem? while hover there are two arrows now, I want the arrow just to be on the one that is hovered and hide it on the `.active`, after mouseout the arrow goes back to the `.active` one):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA2MM.png

This is my css:

```
header nav {
  float: right;
  font-family: 'avenir_lt_std65_medium';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #000000;
}
header nav ul li a.active::before {
  content: ">> ";
}
header nav ul li a:hover:before {
  content: ">> ";
}
```

Comment: You really should abstract your DOM events from your HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this do the trick ?

```css
header nav {
  float: right;
  font-family: 'avenir_lt_std65_medium';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #000000;
}
nav ul li a.active::before {
  content: ">> ";
}
nav ul:hover li a::before {
  content: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover:before {
  content: ">> ";
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="menuitem active">see all projects</a></li>
        <li><a class="menuitem">about</a></li>
        <li><a class="menuitem">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It works but it's missing something. When you hover over the one that is `active` there are no arrows

Comment: Yes, my bad, i did one too many edit. It should work properly now

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to close your question.